# How many warnings will be given for a player?

Tags: rules, cricket, icc

We know that a batsman or a bowler will be given warning for some activities like running on the pitch, moving from the original fielding position before bowling, starts running before bowling,..etc.
Totally, how many warnings will be given for a player for a single match?
After crossing that limitations,what actions will be taken on them?

Promote your answer with some examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Warnings for different actions are separate. There is no accumulation of such warnings across different categories. The Laws of cricket still in general allow the Umpires a great deal of discretion in how things such as warnings are applied. Umpires will often talk to the players and captain informally before issuing formal warnings as stipulated under the rules.

Likewise, if a player has done many bad things in a game in a poor spirit, the match referee has discretion to issue post match fines and/or suspensions.